# User should not be allowed to type zero as the first digit using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I need to validate a number entered by a user in a textbox using JavaScript. The user should not be able to enter 0 as the first digit like 09, 08 etc, wherein he should be allowed to enter 90 , 9.07 etc..

Please help me.. I tried to use the below function but it disallows zero completely:

```
   function AllowNonZeroIntegers(val)
   {
   if ((val > 48 && val < 58) || ((val > 96 && val < 106)) || val == 46 || val == 8 || val == 127 || val == 189 || val == 109 || val == 45 || val == 9)
           return true;
       return false;
   }
```

on

```
 Texbox1.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return AllowNonZeroIntegers(event.keyCode)");   
 Texbox1.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return AllowNonZeroIntegers(event.keyCode)");
```

Comment: Use parseFloat, and then convert to string again. Leading zeros will be removed. Use decimal when parsing, to avoid rounding errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ty this:

```
Texbox1.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return AllowNonZeroIntegers(event)");

function AllowNonZeroIntegers(e) {
    var val = e.keyCode;
    var target = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement;
    if(target.value.length == 0 && val == 48) {
        return false;
    }
    else if ((val >= 48 && val < 58) || ((val > 96 && val < 106)) || val == 46 || val == 8 || val == 127 || val == 189 || val == 109 || val == 45 || val == 9) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/9rZRC/2/)**

Comment: I am receiving this error when I try to add 0 and able to add zero as the first digit.'target.value' is null or not an object

Comment: Edited my answer to support IE < 9 browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Use `charAt()` to control the placement of X at Y:

```
function checkFirst(str){
   if(str.charAt(0) == "0"){
       alert("Please enter a valid number other than '0'");
   }
}
```

Comment: I get the alert for every number that I enter.